# How can i restrict user to copy the content from HTML Container (ie <mx:HTML/>) in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3

In my air application, i have displayed text content in html container. whenever anyone select this content, he/she can easily copy the content.

I want to restrict my text from copy. Any content of the my application, should not be copy by any user..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys Use the following style in body of Content

```
.unselectable{
  -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be to use a transparent .png Image on top of the container so anybody which would want to copy the text will copy the Image! regards aktell

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseChildren and mouseEnabled

```
<mx:HTML id="ht" width="300" height="240" mouseChildren="false" mouseEnabled="false"/>
```